# Test-NetConnection being executed in switch when it should not

Tags: powershell, menu, switch-statement, selection

I have a powershell script that uses a menu and a selection. So loops until selection is 0.  For one selection it tests entered port with "Test-NetConnection".  But for some reason after this is ran, whenever another selection is made it seems "Test-NetConnection" is always ran, the banner shows up in powershell (even though it is very quick, but it shouldn't be executed.

I removed some selections.  And I also have a few custom functions. But not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Powershell...

```
while ($selection -ne 0) {



    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output "__MENU__"
    Write-Output "0. Exit"
    Write-Output "1. Set Target Machines"
    Write-Output "2. Set Save Directory"
    Write-Output "4. Save MSINFO32"
    Write-Output "5. Save All Installed Software"
    Write-Output "9. Save GPO Info (gpresult)
    Write-Output "10. Test WMI"
    Write-Output "11. Test TCP Port"
    Write-Output "14. Test Syslog"
    Write-Output ""
    
    Write-Output "Target Machines: $($targetComputers -Join ',')"
    Write-Output "Save Directory: $savePath`n"
    
    $selection = Read-Host -Prompt "Selection"
    Write-Output ""
    
    switch ($selection) {
        0 { break }
        1 { ... }
        2 { ... }
        11 {
            $testPort = Read-Host -Prompt "TCP Port to Test (Leave blank for default: 80)"
            Write-Output ""
            if (($testPort -eq $null) -Or ($testPort -eq "")) { $testPort = 80 }

            foreach ($computer in $targetComputers) {

                try {
                    $netcon = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer -Port $testPort -ErrorAction "Stop"
                    if($netcon.TcpTestSucceeded) { Write-Output "TCP Port $testPort test was successful on $computer." }
                    else { Write-Warning "TCP Port $testPort test was unsuccessful on $computer." }
                }
                catch { Write-Warning "TCP Port $testPort test was unsuccessful on $computer." }
            }


        } #11

        14 {
            $sysServer = Read-Host -Prompt "Syslog Server (Leave blank for default: ${env:computername})"
            $sysProto = Read-Host -Prompt "Syslog Server Protocol (Leave blank for default: TCP)"
            $sysPort = Read-Host -Prompt "Syslog Server Port (Leave blank for default: 514)"
            Write-Output ""

            if (($sysServer -eq $null) -Or ($sysServer -eq "")) { $sysServer = $env:computername }
            if (($sysProto -eq $null) -Or ($sysProto -eq "")) { $sysProto = "TCP" }
            if (($sysPort -eq $null) -Or ($sysPort -eq "")) { $sysPort = 514 }

            sendSyslog -Server $sysServer -Protocol $sysProto -Port $sysPort
            
        } #14
        default { break }
   } #switch
} #while
```

Comment: **_please strip out everything that does not relate to the problem._** you have a large amount of unneeded code that makes analysis needlessly complicated. lookee ... How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your menu option `"9. Save GPO Info (gpresult)` is missing a closing quote.

Make this easier for yourself and use a [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) for the menu:

```
$menu = @"

__MENU__
0. Exit
1. Set Target Machines
2. Set Save Directory
4. Save MSINFO32
5. Save All Installed Software
9. Save GPO Info (gpresult)
10. Test WMI
11. Test TCP Port
14. Test Syslog

"@
```

Then instead of looping like `while ($selection -ne 0)`, run an endless loop you can exit as soon as the user types a '0'.

```
# enter an endless loop here.
# exit that loop right after the Read-Host when the user type '0'
while ($true) {
    Write-Host $menu

    # some in-between code.. #
    $selection = Read-Host -Prompt "Selection"
    if ($selection -eq '0') { break }  # or exit if you want to stop the entire script here
    # rest of your code.. #
}
```

P.S. anything coming back from `Read-Host` is a **string**, not a number.